# Animating movement on snake in snakeGame

Tags: c++, sfml

I can move in good direction with a snake game but i can't seem to animate "where the head" goes. I have the sprite sheet i made myself(and if i need to upload somehow feel free to tell me) and i refered to this question because apparently the writer already had solved what i need to solve but with its help i still couldn't make it work.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655335/animating-sprites-in-sfml-from-a-sprite-sheet?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here is the code i have come up with that does not work. It is all in the constructor.

```
Game::Game() : myWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "snakeGame!", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar), snake(3) {
    direction = Dir::UP;
    xPos = 20;
    yPos = 40;

    if (!texture.loadFromFile("wholeSnake.png", sf::IntRect(x, y, w, h)))
      {
      throw "error";
      }

      
    switch(direction){
        case Dir::RIGHT: x = 0; y = 0; w = 40; h = 10;   xPos += 1;   sprite.setPosition(xPos + 1, yPos);   break;
        case Dir::LEFT:  x = 0; y = 10; w = 40; h = 10;  xPos -= 1;   sprite.setPosition(xPos - 1, yPos);   break;
        case Dir::UP:    x = 0; y = 20; w = 10; h = 40;  yPos -= 1;   sprite.setPosition(xPos, yPos - 1);   break;
        case Dir::DOWN:  x = 10; y = 20; w = 10; h = 40; yPos += 1;   sprite.setPosition(xPos, yPos + 1);   break;
    }
```

I want to literally, for now, snake change from going left(head to the left) to going up(head up), later i will worry about stuff like animation as intended(i guess this style of doing things first similar but not exactly as i should suits me to certain degree).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

When i was testing this code out before it showed the sprite for a snake going iirc right or left.
Now, it does not show at all, anything. I even changed the `xPos - 1` etc to only `xPos`(because that was what i originally intended to do) and it is still like that.

Lately my code is having these unpredicted behaviors and i am wondering why.

Comment: Don't you think that the first step would be to create all the pngs that represent your animation? Have you done that already?

Comment: I have, and it is all in one place. Well, only for when snake moves straight LEFT, RIGHT, UP and DOWN. It is in a sprite sheet.

Comment: If anyone's wondering, here's how it looks. https://easyupload.io/wrifkn

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly figure out exactly what your code is doing, and why it differs from your expected results.

Comment: Well to be honest i have never used debugger. I am using Visual Studio Code and i do not even know if i can debug on it, for a fact i know i can on VS2019.

Comment: You cannot expect to be able to complete a non-trivial  c++ program without needing to debug it, at some point. I spend just as much time debugging code as writing it.

Comment: Well, maybe the lack of mentioning is to blame for me not ever trying it, but i guess it's more on me for not researching deeper.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, when it try to debug this and set the breakpoint at constructor, i get redirected to `contextSettings.hpp` then it goes two lines there and it makes me quit. I get this error `Unable to open 'dl-error-skeleton.c': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/elf/dl-error-skeleton.c' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/elf/dl-error-skeleton.c').` What is with this?

Comment: I am, by the way, going to `step into` always because everything else makes me exit

Comment: That's part of the C runtime library. There's rarely a need to step into low-level libraries, but if there's a need to do that there's usually an optional debug package that can be installed to do that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What optional debug package? Are you able to share a link?

Comment: The package is different in every Linux distribution. In the current Fedora distribution, this would be the gcc-debuginfo and gcc-debugsource RPMs; and the `debuginfo-install` tool would find and install them. Whatever Linux distribution you're using, you need to investigate and figure out what needs to be done to install debug support for your libraries.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik As far as i know, i have gdb installed on my Ubuntu but i will investigate deeper.